# Can I "move" the screen, but have objects on the screen still moving?

Tags: objective-c, macos

As the title said, I want to move the screen up, so that my app's window can come in from the bottom. What I currently have now is a floating window, whose background has been set to a screenshot of the screen. Like this:
[image: My app's] 
It looks fine to the user, except now any objects that work in the background don't appear above the window, it's basically frozen.

Can I do this? This effect is similar to what Notification Center does in 10.8.

Comment: [Check my GitHub repository](https://github.com/evilGoldfish/SiriBar). In SiriBar.m, a screenshot is taken, and then a full screen window is displayed, with the screenshot as the background. Then, as the 'SiriBar' appears, it comes out of the bottom of the screen, and as such the screenshot is raised up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this, for a certain definition of "can" - there's no API for it, but you can likely use the same SPI that the Finder/Dock/etc uses.  The only complication may lie in needing special privileges, or needing your code to be specially signed - I'm not sure what checks are in place.

It's not too tricky to figure this out; you can use tools like `nm`, `otool` and even `class-dump`.